# Cascading Dropdown not Working using JQuery Ajax in Asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dropdown I want to populate through an item selection of another dropdown in an MVC project using Jquery Ajax. Below is How I am oing about it

**Controller Method**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetBusinessPartnerBankAccounts(long businessPartnerId)
        {
            var businessPartner = _bpService.Get(businessPartnerId);

            var data = businessPartner.BankAccounts.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.AccountNumber + " -- " + x.AccountName + " -- " + x.BankName
            });

            return Json(data);
        }
```

**View** - Select with Id "drpAccounts" is the control I am trying to populate

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BusinessPartnerId, Model.BusinessPartners, "-- Select --", new { @id = "drpBusinessPartner" })
                        <label asp-for="BusinessPartnerId">Business Partner</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <select id="drpAccounts">
                        </select>
                        <label>Bank Account</label>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
           $('#drpBusinessPartner').change(function () {
                var bizId = $('#drpBusinessPartner').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/GoodsReceipt/GetBusinessPartnerBankAccounts',
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { businessPartnerId: bizId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#drpAccounts').html('');
                        $('#drpAccounts').append($('<option>-- Select Bank Account --</option>'));
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('#drpAccounts').append($('<option></option>').val(item.value).html(item.Text));
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (reponse) {
                        alert("error : " + reponse);
                    }
                });
            })
```

I have confirmed that data is being retrieved from the controller when the javascript is fired but the drpAccounts dropdown does not get any sort of reaction. There are no errors and I don't know what is happening. However, if I replace the function in `success` with the following code and use a class selector instead of an Id selector, the dropdown disappears leaving the fetched items as a label.

```
                    $('.dlAccounts').empty();

                        $(data).each(function () {
                            $('<option />', {
                                val: this.value,
                                text: this.text
                            }).appendTo('.dlAccounts');

                        });
```

I have been on this for over 24 hours. Please help.

Comment: Your code would be throwing an `500 Internal Server Error` - you would need it to be `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` but there are numerous other issues with your code and suggest you refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: It would also need to be `.val(item.Value)` (capital `V`)

Comment: Sorry what namespace does `JsonRequestbehavior` belong to? It doesn't find the namespace in my code

Comment: Is this asp.net-mvc or asp.net-core-mvc? (you need to tag your question correctly)

Comment: My apologies. It is asp.net-core-mvc

Comment: No problem - ignore the comment on `JsonRequestBehavior` - that is not applicable to core-mvc (but suggest you study the code in the fiddle)

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't see much of a difference in my code comparing with yours. I have changed `.val(item.value)` appropriately as you said but it's still not working. the ajax works pretty well as I can see data in it when I debug. I don't know if the problem lies with Materialize css which I am using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152597/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kacey-ezerioha).